# Angular UI-Router nested route with id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got two routes in my app, nested into each other with ui-router:

#### app/locations/locations.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('treasuremapApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('locations', {
        url: '/locations',
        templateUrl: 'app/locations/locations.html',
        controller: 'LocationsCtrl'
      });
  });
```

#### and app/locations/location/location.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('treasuremapApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('location', {
        url: '/locations/:id',
        templateUrl: 'app/locations/location/location.html',
        controller: 'LocationCtrl'
      });
  });
```

This works fine flawless most of the time, but when I first on my list of locations, click on one, it gets displayed just fine, even the back button works, but when I then just type `/locations` into the URL bar (any other way without the back button), the router seems to try to open the "lower" route with controller and template but of course is missing the ID from the url then.

I have the feeling my understanding of the ui-router is a bit flawed, so can someone please explain to me, what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You basically have an `if()` configuration. `template = id !=undefined ?First template :Second template`. Not sure what you are trying to do but behavior in address bar is correct with the way those routes are set up

Comment: Are you sure you enter `/locations` in the URL bar? Maybe you entered `/locations/`?

Comment: In addition of above point..If states are really nested you should follow `.` notation while creating states like `locations` & then `locations.location
`

Comment: @MarkVeenstra you were right. I didn't think the additional slash in the URL would make it go to the lower route.

Comment: And I'm currently trying to figure out the way for `locations.location` now. Totally new to the ui-router...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you entered `/locations/` into the URL instead of `/locations`. Entering `/locations/` will trigger the second route, because the `ui-router` would expect that `:id` equals `(empty)`.

Also look this FAQ if you want it to behave differently: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes

> How can I have my routes be activated when the url contains either a trailing slash or not?
>
> Set [strictMode](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.%24urlMatcherFactory#methods_strictmode) to false in your config block:
>
> `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false)`

Comment: Yes, it was about the trailing slash and me not noticing it, when just removed the IDs from the URL. As mentioned in the comments earlier, I did know about that. Unfortunately the `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false)` doesn't seem to work for some reason. Maybe there's a way to just remove any trailing slashes via the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Maybe you are using an older version of ui-router. Check the same link I have given. There is also a solution for older u-routers defined.

Comment: Oh yes, we had version `0.2.10` installed. Just started the project some weeks ago so didn't think it would be that outdated already :)